# how to redirect the user if there are any directory name in the url htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

hello all i am working on a site where i dont want any user to browse my site directory or to view any image/file inside the directory by just typing the address of the image or file in address bar or by any software help.

i think this is possible my .htaccess rewrite rule
can anyone help me please
my site directory names are members,images,ads
from some where on this site i found this

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/news/latestnews/(.*)$
  RewriteCond %$1 ^(.*)2012(.*)$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /news/2012 [R=301,L]
```

which redirects the user to new directory but i dont know how to work with htaccess i can not modify the code

Comment: Not clear on what you need. You want to hide/disallow directory listing or restrict direct access to files within a folder?

Comment: If you don't want those images and whatever to be served when requested via http, then why do you publish them? Don't keep them in the location published by your http server, I'd say. Move them somewhere else.

Comment: i want to redirect the user to index page if there is any directory name on the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add following to top of the htaccess file you already have

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?YOURDOMAINNAME.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|png)$ http://www.YOURDOMAINNAME.com [L]
```

`Options -Indexes` will restrict directory listing

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?YOURDOMAINNAME.*$ [NC]` checks if the request  to a file is from within script or if the request has a referrer from your domain

`RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|png)$ http://www.YOURDOMAINNAME.com [L]` will redirect to your home page, if some one tries to access the file directly. You can added file extension to this rule by separating it by pipe `|` symbol, e.g. `gif|jpg|png|doc|pdf`

Comment: the answer is correct but the only problem is that when ever i click on any linked image in the site by my website source code (view page source in browsers ) the image displays but dosen't redirects